# iOS dylib code signing issue

Tags: ios, code-signing, dylib

I am trying to link my app with dynamic libraries. In the project files of the libraries, the code signing is enabled with "iOS Developer", and the same settings apply to my app. Despite the app will crash when launching with the following error message:

`dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/libTKBool.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DADDB24B-1424-4FC8-BC6F-3F24CFC33CA5/Shapr3D.app/Shapr3D
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DADDB24B-1424-4FC8-BC6F-3F24CFC33CA5/Shapr3D.app/libTKBool.dylib: 
code signature invalid for 
'/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DADDB24B-1424-4FC8-BC6F-3F24CFC33CA5/Shapr3D.app/libTKBool.dylib'
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DADDB24B-1424-4FC8-BC6F-3F24CFC33CA5/Shapr3D.app/libTKBool.dylib: 
code signature invalid for 
'/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/DADDB24B-1424-4FC8-BC6F-3F24CFC33CA5/Shapr3D.app/libTKBool.dylib'`

Checking the validity of the signature of the dylibs results:

`/Users/icsanady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OCCT-ebpdjmtsbjbrzmatuymdkggbpkif/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libTKBO.dylib 
/Users/icsanady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OCCT-ebpdjmtsbjbrzmatuymdkggbpkif/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libTKBO.dylib: valid on disk`

/Users/icsanady/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/OCCT-ebpdjmtsbjbrzmatuymdkggbpkif/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libTKBO.dylib: satisfies its Designated Requirement

I also tried to add a 'Copy files' build phase for the dylibs, and enabling the 'Code Sign on Copy' field, without any success.

So now I have to manually codesign the libs after building. Of course, I could add a script phase, to sign them automatically, but I think Xcode should done this automatically. Is this a bug in Xcode, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Here is the codesign -d result for the dylib signed by Xcode: http://pastebin.com/qhZmBf9C
And here is it when I sign it manually: http://pastebin.com/ywRLQbdx

Comment: From Apple support: "dylibs are not first class citizens", we finally used frameworks, and now everything works fine.